# How to iterate and pick out url strings in json array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am getting the following data back from an api and I need to stipout url's and do something with each url.

I know that I have a JSON array of data but am not sure how to get each individual url string out to a local variable.

Note : \"http... is the next url but I didn't want to take too much room with the output. In theory there could be x number of url strings in the array.

My JSON data is

```
{
    "id": "rec2vApXgBQOjsycn",
    "fields": {
        "STATUS": "N",
        "URL": "[\"https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t35.0-12/16523485_1561982860496646_730734086_o.jpg?_nc_ad=z-m&oh=0b956f001aa4fdcc31564e6cafb9047f&oe=589900EB\",\"http...",
        "FB_ID": "588db784e4b0cfb80f75f951",
        "EVENT_ID": "5432"
    },
    "createdTime": "2017-02-04T21:29:02.000Z"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fields.URL.forEach(function(url) {
   console.log(url); // this will print out your URL.
});
```